# I am displaying dynamic data on this React Boostrap Slider. Is there a way to make the code more efficient?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

this is my first post here. I am building a React Boostrap Carousel that pulls Movie data from the database and displays it. I am new to React and programming in general. So far i  made the code work. But i do not know how to handle the images. The images are stores in React **src/assets/imgs. **. Should i store a reference to the image in the database like so *../../assets/imgs/the-batman.jpg* and then display it? If so later on on the project the admin will have to create a MovieOfTheMonth. He should be able to input movie title, descrition etc, and also upload a movie image. Is there a way when the image is uploaded it, to store it to a specific folder, in this case src/assets/imgs and also create a reference in the database? I do not need the solution here, just to tell me if it is achievable. Finally is there a way to improve my code?

`this is my full code for this component`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Carousel.css'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import axios from 'axios';


 const CarouselHero = () => {

    //boostrap code
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
      setIndex(selectedIndex);
    };

    //Get Movies of the month
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])
    const getMovie = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/moviesOfTheMonth")
      .then((res) => {
          const myMovie = res.data
          myMovie.push()
          setMovie(myMovie);
      })
    }
    useEffect(() => getMovie(), []);
  return (
     <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} fade> 
          {movie.map((item) => {
            const {id, title, description} = item.Movie
            return (
              <Carousel.Item  interval={2000}>
              <img
                src={require("../../assets/imgs/the-batman.jpg")}
                alt="First slide"
              />
            <Carousel.Caption >
              <h1>{title}</h1>
              <p>{description}</p>
              <button>Book Now</button>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
            )
          })}
    </Carousel> 
    
    
  );
};

export default CarouselHero;
```

Comment: It would be better to use the backend to store images and fetch their URL in react using the endpoint http://localhost:4000/moviesOfTheMonth

Comment: I second @FaisalNazik. Use backend to serve images. You can have a specific route configured to serve these images from a directory on the backend. Save just the relative url on your DB, and on the frontend (for both admin and user sites) concat the backend url + relative url from db to show the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think technically it is achievable to iterate over the assets folder and create database entries for new images (create and compare hash?), but it is usually not how you do it. I would put images in some file storage like S3 and reference them with id.

I don't know who the admin will be in your project, but if admin is rather a non technical person, you could create (or use a template of course) a small and simple admin dashboard, where he/she can maintain a movie of the month via UI.

FFinally some remarks on your code:

- `const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => { setIndex(selectedIndex); };` - If you need only first, but not second, third etc. argument, you can just leave it out: `(selectedIndex) => ...`
- `const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])` - don't forget to use semicolon after every statement. (They are optional, but are useful sometimes to avoid  weird errors). Also, you have a list here. So maybe better call it "movies".
- `myMovie.push()` - What are you trying to push here?
- `useEffect(() => getMovie(), []);` - Usually you define and call async function directly in useEffect. Don't you get any hints or warning?
- `movie.map((item) => {` - When you iterate and get a list back React needs a key on every element (here on Carousel.Item). Don't just use the index, as it is a bad practice. Always try to find id property in your data.
- `const {id, title, description} = item.Movie` - Why is the data nested by Movie object? Can't you just say item.id, item.title, item.description?

Comment: Pardon the late reply. Thanks for your answer. 
- i corrected the mistakes and placed a Key for every element 
-myMovie.push() was leftover code for something i never did, and don't quite remember what was my intention. 
- Because Movie is an Object inside MoviesOfTheMonth so i iterate over every movie of the month and access the Movie Object with the data i want. 
I am sure there are better ways to do the things i do, but i am in learning mode and there are a lot to focus on, i will later try to improve the way i write and make my code more dry